# How does Chrome bypass proxychains proxying?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy

I noticed that when I launch Chrome with proxychains :

```
$ proxychains google-chrome
```

Every request is correctly proxied, **except those sent to Google websites**! For instance, when I stop the proxy configured in the proxychains conf, with my proxied Chrome I cannot access any website (err_connection_refused), except Google.

I tried the same test with Firefox: every request is proxied by proxychains, **including those sent to Google**.

I know there are other ways to proxy requests that would also work with Google, but I am more interested to know why the proxychains method does not work when you visit Google on Chrome.

Internally, proxychains uses the LD_PRELOAD environment variable to wrap the necessary system calls and proxy all requests transparently. I wasn't expecting Chrome to be able to bypass this wrapping. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

### **Proxychains Bug/Incompatibility :**

There is a bug with chrome caused apparently by the sandbox feature; check  [Issue 45](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/issues/45)

### **Proxychains Limit :**

Proxychains could have leaks in many situations here are some of them as example

- Child process are not proxied (chrome as example could use many process other than the main one... **Solution :** a work around could be modifying the binary location)
- Socks v4 Proxys can not tunnel DNS request (**Solution :** use instead Socks v5)
- Incompatibility with some sandbox feature/applications, as they use kernel userspace feature to be separated from the main system, proxychains does not see/intercept their connections (**Solution :** combine proxychains with iptables)

### **Alternative :**

You can try [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) as alternative, it's often available the distro repos, `apt-get install tsocks` or `dnf install tsocks` etc.